# In quaternions, and other hypergeometrics, is sqrt in a^2=b considered multivalued?

Tags: roots, quaternions, roots-of-unity

In a number system with multiple nonreals, p<sup>2</sup>=1, q<sup>2</sup>=-1, and/or r<sup>2</sup>=0 should have multiple solutions, right? For example, in the quaternions, q could be *i*, *j*, or *k*. Is it multivalued then?

And what happens when you're in a mixed signature? If I'm not mistaken, any combination of positive roots could be a part of q, and any combination of positive or negative roots could be a part of r, as long as q contains one negative root and r contains one root of zero.

```
i2 = (iJ)2 = ... = -1
ε2 = (εi)2 = (εiJ)2 = ... = 0
```

I'm being very careful not to write $\mathbb"\sqrt-1 = i"$ and so on because I know they're not supposed to be identically equal, or $\mathbb(ij=-1$).

**But that just begs the question, what is sqrt(-1), etc. in quaternions and beyond?** Is it considered multivalued or undefined or what?

Personally I would lean toward a separate variant of sqrt derived from each generator, so sqrt<sub>i</sub>(-1) is unambiguously i via i<sup>2</sup>=-1. The general sqrt(-1) would be undefined, since none of the generators are identically equal to it. But I imagine I'm completely alone on this one.

Sorry about my formatting and lack of math background/vocabulary. Also this will likely be marked a duplicate of another question, but I couldn't find the right one.

Comment: The thing is, I don't even know how to answer that for complex numbers. Do you consider the expression $\sqrt{-1}$ to be "multivalued" in $\mathbb{C}$? If yes, I'm not sure why you couldn't say the same in $\mathbb{H}$. I'm not sure what it means exactly though. My advice: don't write $\sqrt{a}$ when $a$ has several square roots, unless you make it very clear that you fix one. It's also not a notation usually used in non-commutative contexts, but after all why not.

Comment: To supplement Captain Lama's comment: There is a $2$-sphere's worth of "square roots of $-1$" in the quaternions, namely the set of $ai + bj + ck$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, not just the six you mention. In complex analysis, we can pick holomorphic branches of "classical multi-valued functions," including $\log$ and roots, because the values form a discrete set. There's no comparable prospect for square roots in the quaternions.

Comment: Right you are, thank you both. I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641461/what-is-the-sqrt-1-when-working-in-a-quaternion-space?rq=1) in the meantime (flagged myself)